# jQuery when to use if statements and when to use functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

I'm often confused wether to use a new function or just an if statement. Most of the time I choose to use if statements, wich can lead to 9 diffrent if statements below each other. There must be a cleaner way to do this. What do you advise? When should I use if statements and when should I use functions.

**Example 1**

```
if(boolean1 === true){
    example1();
    }

    example1(){
    alert('Hello world');
    }
```

**Example 2**

```
if(boolean1 === true)
{
alert('Hello world'); 
}
```

Comment: You should rather use switch for multiple condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions are mostly purpose for "code once and use more"
if that statements of process you have to use more than one time in script,
than you have to make a function,
or if you needed that code only at once than not any reason to make it function, 
just create statement and use it.